# CacheDependency is not evicting cache under load (with virtual path provider)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, dispose, invalidation

We are using Virtual Path Provider to retrieve the items from the filesystem for specific extensions. The base implementation does return the following

```
        if (Handler != null)
        {
            return new MyCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
        }
        else
        {
            return Previous.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
        }
```

The MyCacheDependency uses the following Insert on the HttpContext.Current.Cache Object with the corresponding CacheItemRemovedCallback

```
CacheItemRemovedCallback onCacheItemRemoved = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(this.MyCacheItemRemovedCallbackMethod);
lock (_cache)
                {
                    _cache.Insert(key, value, new CacheDependency(virtualPath), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, onCacheItemRemoved);
                }
```

My Implementation of MyCacheItemRemovedCallbackMethod is

```
// I did read that this needs to be a static implementation and thread-safe too
 public void MyCacheItemRemovedCallbackMethod(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
        {   
            this.SetUtcLastModified(DateTime.UtcNow);
            this.Invalidate();
            cacheRemoveReason = reason;

            switch (cacheRemoveReason.ToString())
            {
                case dependencyChanged:
                    {
                        // what should be disposed here?
                        this.CacheDependencyDispose();
                        this.Dispose();
                        break;
                    }
                case expired:
                    {
                        // what should be disposed here?
                        this.CacheDependencyDispose();
                        this.Dispose();
                        break;
                    }
                case removed:
                    {   
                        // what should be disposed here?
                        this.CacheDependencyDispose();
                        this.Dispose();
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                        this.CacheDependencyDispose();
                        this.Dispose();
                        break;
            }
        }
```

The above works like a charm in most environments but when there is a heavy load on the system, the cache is not being evicted properly.

> Problem

This happens ,under heavy load, when the item is being updated in the filesystem and at the same time, there are multiple requests send to the resource. I am still assuming that the Cache is being removed but we could still see the old content in the our application.

I could see that the use-case for removed being evoked even before expired since the load is being freed up. I could also see in the logs that mycallback method is being evoked correctly but the webpage is not bringing the latest contents from the filesystem.

If remove is being done to free up memory, the latest cache.insert is not even updating the cache correctly.

**Suggestions / Feedback**

- Am I NOT disposing a particular dependency correctly in each of the
  above scenarios? Any feedback is appreciated.
- Am I missing any setting in the virtual path provider that is causing this issue?
- Is there an application or page level setting that needs to be
  enabled /    disabled?
- Any other items that I am missing?

Update:

My invalidate does a NotifyDependencyChanged

```
base.NotifyDependencyChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at a solution. Basically, NotifyDependencyChanged is having the value of the lastwritetime UTC of the object that has been added to the dependency.

In that case, we would not have to explicitly set the this.UtcLastModified to DateTime.Now. I also noted that CacheItemRemovedCallback is only used for notification (to cache, logs etc) and cannot be used to dispose dependencies.

Negotiating a couple of other best practices, I was able to get the below code to work.

```
public void MyCacheItemRemovedCallbackMethod(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
        {   
            this.Invalidate();
            cacheRemoveReason = reason;

            switch (cacheRemoveReason.ToString())
            {
                case dependencyChanged:
                    {
                        Log.Debug("I am logging my reason with datetime modified");
                        break;
                    }
                case expired:
                    {
                       Log.Debug("I am logging my reason with datetime modified");
                        break;
                    }
                case removed:
                    {   
                        Log.Debug("I am logging my reason with datetime modified");
                       break;
                    }
                default:
                        Log.Debug("I am logging my reason with datetime modified");
                        break;
            }
        }
```